# Replace in a list of lists in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

So I have a function that replaces an element of a list with the corespondent element in a list o pairs for example if i have this : (i have a list) and ((have not) (list queue)) it will return (i not a queue)

```
   (define replacecoresp
(lambda (ls a-list)
    (map (lambda (x)
           (let ((lookup (assq x a-list)))
             (if lookup
                 (cadr lookup)
                 x)))
         ls)))
```

unfortunately it doesn't work for a list of lists of lists etc what I want is to do this :
if I have a list (i have ( a list) of (list ( list and list ))) and ((list queue) (have not)) the result should be (I not (a queue) of (queue (queue and queue))) I hope you got the idea :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (replacecoresp ls a-list)
  (cond ((null? ls) '())
        ((not (list? ls))
         (cond ((assq ls a-list) => cadr)
               (else  ls)))
        (else (cons (replacecoresp (car ls) a-list)
                    (replacecoresp (cdr ls) a-list)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(replacecoresp '(I have (a list) of (list (list and list)))
               '((list queue) (have not)))

> (I not (a queue) of (queue (queue and queue)))
```

Explanation: When traversing a list of lists (say, `ls`) you need to consider three cases:

1. `ls` is empty, return the empty list
2. `ls` is an atom not a list, process the element
3. `ls` is a list, invoke the recursion on both the `car` and the `cdr`
   of the list and combine the results

In the particular case of your question, `cons` is used in the third step for combining the solution; and the second case is the part where we check to see if the current symbol is in the association list, replacing it if it was found or leaving the symbol untouched if not. I used a shortcut for writing less code in this step, but you can replace the inner `cond` with this snippet of code if it's clearer:

```
(let ((lookup (assq ls a-list)))
  (if lookup
      (cadr lookup)
      ls))
```

Another way to express the solution is to use a `map` on the list like this:

```
(define(replacecoresp ls a-list)
  (if (not (list? ls))
      (cond ((assq ls a-list) => cadr)
            (else  ls))
      (map (lambda (l) (replacecoresp l a-list)) ls)))
```

Comment: But what if I want to replace a whole list is not possible for example (I have (a list) of (list (a list))) and ((a list) L) the output should be ( I have L of (list L))

Comment: assq compares elements with eq? and (eq? '(a list) '(a list)) evaluates to #f.  You need to use equal? to compare lists and the assq version of that is `assoc`

Comment: yes but if I use assoc in spite of using assq I don't get the result because it will never enter there because I check if it's not a list so...

Comment: (define (replacedeep ls a-list)
  (cond 
    ((null? ls) '() )
    ((assoc ls a-list)
         (let ((lookup (assoc ls a-list)))
           (if lookup
               (cadr lookup)
               ls)))
    ((not (list? ls))
     (let ((lookup (assoc ls a-list)))
           (if lookup
               (cadr lookup)
               ls)))
    (else (cons (replacedeep (car ls) a-list)
                (replacedeep (cdr ls) a-list)))))

Comment: @IonelMerca what you're asking in the first comment, is a different question. An association list is made of a lists of lists, where each sublist is an association of an identifier and a value, the identifier typically is an atom, _not_ another list. I guess it's possible to write such a procedure, but it'd be more complicated, even more if the "identifier" is an arbitrarily nested list. And no, replacing `assq` with `assoc` won't be enough, you'd have to rewrite the recursion. If possible, stick with atom identifiers in the association list.

Comment: @IonelMerca using the exact definition of what you have in your comment for replacedeep, executing (replacedeep '(I have (a list) of (list (a list))) '(((a list) L))) produces (I have L of (list L))